# Is there any way to set permanently the News Feed in the option "More Recent"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

There are 2 options, "More Recent" and "Featured Histories" (I don't know exactly the name in English since my Facebook is in Spanish). I set the option in "More Recent" but everytime I leave Facebook and enter again the option is set to "Featured Histories". Is there any way to set permanently the News Feeds in the option "More Recent"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are following options (in English) for News Feed:

- Top Stories
- Most Recent

When you login to Facebook using official link (https://www.facebook.com/), it shows *Top Stories* based on your preferences (if you have any) otherwise Top Stories by default. I don't see any setting to change it permanently.

To see the Most Recent feed, use `?sk=h_chr` with the Facebook login link:
https://www.facebook.com/?sk=h_chr

`?sk=h_chr` sets the feed to Most Recent every time you open.

Other option is using [FB Purity](http://www.fbpurity.com/) browser add-on. It has an option to keep News Feed on Most Recent. This is FB Purity page - [Fluff Busting ( FB ) Purity](https://www.facebook.com/fluffbustingpurity).